# Problem Updating - linux-image-extra-4.4.0-72-generic

Tags: updates

Any ideas how to fix this?

I tried using autoclean, rebooting, and manuallt deleting linux-image-extra-4.4.0-72-generic from /boot and nothing helps.

sudo aptitude upgrade -f

```
The following partially installed packages will be configured:
  initramfs-tools linux-image-extra-4.4.0-72-generic linux-image-extra-4.4.0-78-generic linux-signed-generic 
  linux-signed-image-generic 
No packages will be installed, upgraded, or removed.
0 packages upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B of archives. After unpacking 0 B will be used.
Setting up initramfs-tools (0.122ubuntu8.8) ...
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
Setting up linux-image-extra-4.4.0-72-generic (4.4.0-72.93) ...
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal 4.4.0-72-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-72-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools 4.4.0-72-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-72-generic
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-72-generic
W: mdadm: /etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf defines no arrays.

gzip: stdout: No space left on device
E: mkinitramfs failure find 141 cpio 141 gzip 1
update-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-72-generic with 1.
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools exited with return code 1
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-extra-4.4.0-72-generic (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Setting up linux-image-extra-4.4.0-78-generic (4.4.0-78.99) ...
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal 4.4.0-78-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-78-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools 4.4.0-78-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-78-generic
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-78-generic
W: mdadm: /etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf defines no arrays.

gzip: stdout: No space left on device
E: mkinitramfs failure find 141 cpio 141 gzip 1
update-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-78-generic with 1.
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools exited with return code 1
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-extra-4.4.0-78-generic (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-signed-image-generic:
 linux-signed-image-generic depends on linux-image-extra-4.4.0-78-generic; however:
  Package linux-image-extra-4.4.0-78-generic is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package linux-signed-image-generic (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                                                          dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-signed-generic:
 linux-signed-generic depends on linux-signed-image-generic (= 4.4.0.78.84); however:
  Package linux-signed-image-generic is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package linux-signed-generic (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              Processing triggers for initramfs-tools (0.122ubuntu8.8) ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-78-generic
W: mdadm: /etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf defines no arrays.

gzip: stdout: No space left on device
E: mkinitramfs failure find 141 cpio 141 gzip 1
update-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-78-generic with 1.
dpkg: error processing package initramfs-tools (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-extra-4.4.0-72-generic
 linux-image-extra-4.4.0-78-generic
 linux-signed-image-generic
 linux-signed-generic
 initramfs-tools
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
Failed to perform requested operation on package.  Trying to recover:
Setting up linux-image-extra-4.4.0-72-generic (4.4.0-72.93) ...
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal 4.4.0-72-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-72-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools 4.4.0-72-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-72-generic
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-72-generic
W: mdadm: /etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf defines no arrays.

gzip: stdout: No space left on device
cpio: write error: Broken pipe
find: ‘standard output’: Broken pipe
find: write error
E: mkinitramfs failure find 1 cpio 1 gzip 1
update-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-72-generic with 1.
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools exited with return code 1
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-extra-4.4.0-72-generic (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Setting up initramfs-tools (0.122ubuntu8.8) ...
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
Setting up linux-image-extra-4.4.0-78-generic (4.4.0-78.99) ...
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal 4.4.0-78-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-78-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools 4.4.0-78-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-78-generic
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-78-generic
W: mdadm: /etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf defines no arrays.

gzip: stdout: No space left on device
cpio: write error: Broken pipe
find: ‘standard output’: Broken pipe
find: write error
E: mkinitramfs failure find 1 cpio 1 gzip 1
update-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-78-generic with 1.
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools exited with return code 1
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-extra-4.4.0-78-generic (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-signed-image-generic:
 linux-signed-image-generic depends on linux-image-extra-4.4.0-78-generic; however:
  Package linux-image-extra-4.4.0-78-generic is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package linux-signed-image-generic (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-signed-generic:
 linux-signed-generic depends on linux-signed-image-generic (= 4.4.0.78.84); however:
  Package linux-signed-image-generic is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package linux-signed-generic (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for initramfs-tools (0.122ubuntu8.8) ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-78-generic
W: mdadm: /etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf defines no arrays.

gzip: stdout: No space left on device
cpio: write error: Broken pipe
find: ‘standard output’: Broken pipe
find: write error
E: mkinitramfs failure find 1 cpio 1 gzip 1
update-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-78-generic with 1.
dpkg: error processing package initramfs-tools (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-extra-4.4.0-72-generic
 linux-image-extra-4.4.0-78-generic
 linux-signed-image-generic
 linux-signed-generic
 initramfs-tools
```

Answer (score 1):

Unless your /boot partition is incredibly small it should be able to handle more than two versions of the kernel.  I see a "no space left on device" error but not sure if that relates to a kernel upgrade or something else.  If /boot is full, look for some really big file that obviously doesn't belong there and move it to a temporary location such as in your /home directory.

If by "manually deleted" 4.4.0.72 or parts of it you mean you did a "rm" on individual files you could have problems.  Assuming you didn't do that. see what version of the kernel you are currently running.  If it is not newer than 4.4.0.72, reboot.  It's not clear (at least to me) if your upgrade to 4.4.0.78 was successful.

uname -a

Get rid of oldest kernel version

sudo apt-get purge linux-image-4.4.0.72-generic

sudo apt autoremove -- purge

The above will work in most cases.  Since you manually deleted a portion of the 4.4.0.72 kernel, you will be getting complaints every time you try to do an upgrade.  You need to make apt happy again.  Try these commands:

sudo dpkg -P linux-image-4.4.0-72-generic

This tells the system to delete the package. This is likely to result in a complaint about broken dependencies. In this case, you should add the package(s) it claims as being dependent on the old kernel you just tried to remove.  In your case, this would be dependencies such as

sudo dpkg -P linux-image-extra-4.0.0-72-generic

And so on.

Again, be sure to do a uname -a and verify what version of the kernel you are currently running before deleting anything!

Comment: Unfortunately, I did  "rm" to remove some files.

Comment: Unfortunately, I did  "rm" to remove some files.

uname -a

    Linux nuc 4.4.0-78-generic #99-Ubuntu SMP Thu Apr 27 15:29:09 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

sudo apt-get purge linux-image-4.4.0.72-generic

I get this - https://pastebin.com/SE2xJmd6

sudo apt autoremove --purge

I get this - https://pastebin.com/mzsvrUkv

Comment: If /boot is completely full, try removing the oldest kernel version that you HAVEN'T fiddled with by manually deleting anything.   This looks like sudo dpkg -P linux-image-4.4.0-62-generic

Comment: sudo dpkg -P linux-image-4.4.0-62-generic 

dpkg: dependency problems prevent removal of linux-image-4.4.0-62-generic:
 linux-image-extra-4.4.0-62-generic depends on linux-image-4.4.0-62-generic.
 linux-signed-image-4.4.0-62-generic depends on linux-image-4.4.0-62-generic (= 4.4.0-62.83).

dpkg: error processing package linux-image-4.4.0-62-generic (--purge):
 dependency problems - not removing
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-4.4.0-62-generic